# Select a column in dataframe from csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to select the 'Name' column from a sample csv file named gradesM3.csv.

I have been following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/dunder-data/selecting-subsets-of-data-in-pandas-6fcd0170be9c) but when it comes to selecting a single column, it doesn't work anymore.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('gradesM3.csv')
df
```

The output:

```
Out[9]: 
  StudentID;Name;Assignment1;Assignment2;Assignment3
0                   s123456;Michael Andersen;11;7;-3
1                    s123789;Bettina Petersen;0;4;10
2                        s123579;Marie Hansen;10;4;7
```

I believe there's already something wrong here as from what I've seen on other discussions, it's supposed to look more like a table.

When I try to display only the 'Name' column, with this command:

```
df['Name']
```

It returns:

```
KeyError: 'Name'
```

**To sum up, I am trying to import my CSV file as a proper dataframe so I can work with it**

Thanks

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('gradesM3.csv',sep=';')

Comment: Thank you, that worked!!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Thanks to W-B's comment, it worked with this code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('gradesM3.csv',sep=';')
```